# Copy CSV values from one CSV file to matching CSV values of another file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have two CSV files and both have one common column, the EmailAddress header.
The powershell script is supposed to copy the phone number from one csv to the other where the email address is matching.

The first CSV file, users.csv, is a Get-ADUser csv export with the following headers:

```
"SamAccountName";"DisplayName";"Surname";"GivenName";"telephoneNumber";"EmailAddress"
```

The second CSV file is an export of our address book and has the following headers:

```
"RoomNr";"Name";"TelNr";"Cordless";"Fax";"Department";"Title";"EmailAddress"
```

My goal is to copy the "TelNr" to users.csv, where the the value of "EmailAddress" is equal.

My idea looks like this:

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path C:\users.csv -Delimiter ";"
$addressbook = Import-Csv -Path C:\addressbook.csv -Delimiter ";"


foreach ($record in $users) {
    $mail = $record.EmailAddress
    $match = $addressbook | Where-Object {$_.EmailAddress -like $mail}
    
    $record.telephoneNumber = $match.TelNr
}
```

but it's not working at all. Nothing is written in the file. Any idea where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're **so close**..

All that is missing is to output the updated `$users` object array as CSV file.

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\users.csv' -Delimiter ";"
$addressbook = Import-Csv -Path 'C:\addressbook.csv' -Delimiter ";"

foreach ($record in $users) { 
    $mail = $record.EmailAddress
    $record.telephoneNumber = ($addressbook | Where-Object { $_.EmailAddress -eq $mail }).TelNr
}

# output to new csv file
$users | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\UsersComplete.csv' -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```